# Python.: Why product of empty list output is "1"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am using 'prod' method from 'math' package to find the product of a list. Somehow I don't understand why the output is 1 for below operation although its an empty list.

```
from math import prod

a = [1,2,3]

print(prod(a[:0]))
1

print(bool(a[:0]))
False
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod

Comment: What else did you expect ?

Comment: Ideally, for any two lists `a` and `b`, you want `prod(a+b) == prod(a) * prod(b)`. The only way to make this work when `a` is the empty list is if `prod([]) == 1`.

Comment: @Stef: mh, the only way ? You might also have the conventions `prod([]) == None` and `None * x = x` or similar.

Comment: @Yves "None x" should intuitively be "none"… Practically `None * x` is a `TypeError`…

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, if we can add definitions for `*` like that, I'd also like to have `[1,2,3,4] * 1.5 == [1,2,3,4,1,2]`, but that's not how python does it.

Comment: @deceze: I was contradicting "the only way".

Comment: @Stef: because it's the only way, presumably...

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the description at [math module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod). If the list is empty the returned value is 1

> math.prod(iterable, *, start=1)
>
> Calculate the product of all the elements in the input iterable. The default start value for the product is 1.
>
> When the iterable is empty, return the start value. This function is
> intended specifically for use with numeric values and may reject
> non-numeric types.

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual mathematical convention, which is quite natural.

The sum of no element is defined as 0. (If you append x, the new sum is 0+x.)

The product of no element is defined as 1.  (If you append x, the new product is 1.x .)

---

For a similar reason, the minimum of no element is ∞ and the maximum is -∞. The union of no set is the empty set. The intersection of no set is the universe. The logical or of no boolean is false. The logical and of no boolean is true.